# Default cache-control directives (and behaviour) when header returns only private

Tags: cache, http-headers, cache-control

I just checked the cache-control header returned by webmasters.stackexchange.com. The only directive present in the response is `cache-control: private`. In this case, what are the default values for other directives including max-age? Should a client re-validate (checking if the content is modified on the server) for every request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla has a [HTTP Caching FAQ](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/http/http-caching-faq.html) that says:

> [In this case] then the expiration calculation is essentially the algorithm described in RFC 2616 section 13.2.
>
> ...
>
> The expiration time is computed as follows:
>
> ```
> expirationTime = responseTime + freshnessLifetime - currentAge
> ```
>
> where `responseTime` is the time at which the response was received according to the browser.
>
> ...
>
> The freshness lifetime is calculated based on several headers. ... If [neither `max-age`nor `Expires` header are] present, then we look for a `Last-Modified` header.  If this header is present, then the cache's freshness lifetime is equal to the value of the `Date` header minus the value of the `Last-modified` header divided by 10.

When I investigated this heuristic of `Last-modified / 10` for [Why is this response being cached?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53942/why-is-this-response-being-cached), I found that all major browsers appear to use this same heuristic.

According to [Cache-Control - HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control), clients must only revalidate if one of the following headers is present:

- `no-cache`
- `max-age=0, must-revalidate`

Since neither of those headers are present in this case, no revalidation needs to occur.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something. But what if last-modified header isn't present?  I couldn't find one in the response of webmasters.stackexchange.com. In such cases, do browsers use some default value?

Comment: Most pages on this site have `Last-modified`: `curl --head https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/134583/default-cache-control-directives-and-behaviour-when-header-returns-only-privat/134589` shows  `last-modified: Tue, 01 Jun 2021 11:11:17 GMT`.      It appears that the home page does not and I'm not sure what browsers assume in that case.  I'd assume they have to use "modified just now" as the default because there is no other sane assumption.